# make - Why are some pattern rules marked implicit?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on a header file dependency Makefile. This is a very reduced version of the code:

```
cdeps/%.mk:: %
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    ./cdeps.sh cdeps $* .

%.cpp.o: %.cpp cdeps/%.cpp.mk
    g++ -c $< -o $@ -I.

include $(shell find cdeps -type f 2>/dev/null)
```

a.cpp includes b.cpp; cdeps.sh adds dependencies to other cdeps/%.mk for included files.

So when I 'make a.cpp.o', first cdeps/a.cpp.mk is created, then a.cpp.o (exactly as expected).
Then cdeps/a.cpp.mk is deleted. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about implicit rules and when the targets are deleted, and how to prevent that, here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html

Comment: It says nothing about how explicit rules have their output deleted.

Comment: It says: _The second difference is that if make does create `b` in order to update something else, it deletes `b` later on after it is no longer needed. Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also does not exist after make. make reports the deletion to you by printing a `rm -f` command showing which file it is deleting._